# Mesh "expands" in object mode?

Tags: edit-mode

[image]

As you can see in the above image, my mesh in edit mode, or at least certain parts of it, exist in the size intended for everything to be. But it sort of starts to "expand" and clips through other parts of the mesh in object mode.

Why is this, and how do I fix it?

edit: here is the modifier tab
[image]

Comment: Could you show your modifer tab or share file?

Comment: yes I added it.

Comment: unhide all geometry in edit mode. Could be that something was hidden which can only be seen in object mode. Disable the modifier to check whether it is caused by the modifier.

Comment: could you please share your file?

Answer (score 1):

Things changing when entering/exiting edit mode are usually due to modifiers. Try disabling them to see if any is affecting your mesh on object mode.

As you have an armature modifier on the stack, I'd guess that some bone is scaled differently from (1,1,1), and that scales its assigned vertices.